# Sharepoint 2013 foundation display language

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results, language

Only way we get search working is to change above settings:
"User Name" -> My Settings -> My Language and Region -> My Display Languages.
First one should be my native language and second one should be English(US)

Is it possible to change these settngs centrally or with GPO so that everyone would have it like that?
Non-admin accounts cannot change these settings at all.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Foundation users do not have My Site available, this means that individual users cannot manage Language settings by themselves. I think you can create user properties in your AD to sync over to your SP (assuming this is your setup) wherein the value of the first language is the native language.

Comment: Is there an easier way to change language settings for all users from sharepoint?